# SwiftUI ScrollView only scroll in one direction

Tags: swift, scrollview, swiftui

Trying to make a custom list using a view as the list row style (to get rid of the ugly line separates in the list by default).

However, once I put my ZStack rows inside a scroll view, the scroll view scrolls in both directions and not just vertically.

Here is the contentView:

```swift
NavigationView {
            ScrollView{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    ForEach(friends) { friends in
                        NavigationButton(destination: MessageDetailView(friend: friends)) {
                            CustomListItem(friend: friends)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Messages"))
        }
```

and here is the customListItem:

```swift
Group{
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .shadow(radius: 1, y:1)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, height: 75)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(friend.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("\(friend.date, formatter: dateFormatter)")
                        }
                        Text(friend.messagesReceived[0])
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        }       .lineLimit(nil)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }.padding(10)
                }.padding([.leading, .trailing])
        }
```

Is there any way I can limit the scrolling to vertical or force a frame on this?

Trying to use the .frame(...) modifier does not work as I've tried it. This results in the view not loading at all.

Example Images:

[image: Without ScrollView]

[image: With ScrollView wrapping the VStack]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be achieved with a `GeometryReader`. Wrap your `ScrollView` in one and then set the width of your `VStack`.

[GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) is a super easy, and pretty useful trick to have in your belt for SwiftUI :)

Here's how I got it working with your code:

```swift
NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        ForEach(self.friends) { friend in
                            NavigationButton(destination: MessageDetailView(friend: friend)) {
                                CustomListItem(friend: friend)
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Messages"))
            }
        }
```

Comment: Genius, this worked! Didn't know about GeometryReader -> will look into it! thanks :)

Comment: @piebie I knew about GeometryReader but your answer is awesome because it shows how it can be used with VStack and Scrollview to great effect.  In my case, the layout broke on rotation and now it works like a champ thanks to you.

Answer (score 20):

As of Xcode 11 beta 3 (11M362v) there is an `axes` parameter when constructing a `ScrollView` which can be set to `.horizontal` or `.vertical`

```swift
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) { ... }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!  Note that even with `.vertical` added as shown, if the content of the ScrollView is wider than the width of the ScrollView, you can still get some sideways scrolling. Constraining the content width fixes this.

Answer (score 6):

Using iOS 14, Swift 5, SwiftUI 2.0

This is the answer... you can use both vertical and horizontal in a set.

```
ScrollView([.vertical,.horizontal]) {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although in most cases the above answers works but none of them did work for me!

In my case, the problem was the scrollView children which were wider than the scrollView!

adding a static width to them did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try being more specific with the scroll direction like this

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like this answer doesn't really add anything more than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56877403/11384392) does; without some more content to differentiate your answer from the linked one, yours will likely be downvoted or removed. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59033434/edit) to put some more explanation/content/references in. If you aren't able to, no worries! There are plenty of other questions out there; just remove this post and try again on another question. Happy answering!