# How do I change scrollview's scroll direction in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I was trying to implement vertical scroll with image and text but I am not able to achieve it.

I tried on both Xcode beta 1 & 2. 
[image: Here is the code snippet]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI ScrollView only scroll in one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677633/swiftui-scrollview-only-scroll-in-one-direction)

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap both the `Text` and the `Image` in a `VStack` and be sure that there is enough content inside the `ScrollView` to fall outside it's bounds (in the right direction - vertically in your case):

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ForEach (1...100) {_ in
            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            Text("my text")
        }
    }
}
```

---

You could easily try it out in a Playground like this :

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct LiveView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach (1...100) {_ in
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    Text("Some text")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: LiveView())
```